# How to mount a Sinatra app in a Padrino app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, padrino

Resque/Sidekiq come with a web frontend, which is a Sinatra app.

The way to mount this in a Rails app is to add this to routes (http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq?view=asciicast):

```
mount Sidekiq::Web, at: "/sidekiq"
```

How do i mount this in a Padrino app?
Mapping it in config.ru like other Rack apps does not work

```
map '/sidekiq' do
  run Sidekiq::Web
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Padrino uses Padrino.mount which expects apps to respond to dependencies and setup_application. This hack (https://gist.github.com/1718723) allows you to mount a Sinatra application inside a Padrino application

Answer (score 1):

Padrino app is a rack app and in `config.ru` you would see

```
require ::File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/boot.rb'
run Padrino.application
```

You can change this to use Rack::URLMap

```
require ::File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/boot.rb'
run Rack::URLMap.new("/sidekiq" => Sidekiq::Web.new, "/app" => Padrino.application.new)
```

Comment: This does not work if i use padrino s to start server. URLMap works only if i use rackup to start server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `gem 'sidekiq'` to Gemfile
2. `bundle install`
3. Add following lines to `config/boot.rb`

   ```rb
   Padrino.before_load do
     Padrino.dependency_paths << Padrino.root('app/workers/*.rb')
   end
   ```
4. Add following lines to `config/apps.rb`

   ```rb
   require 'sidekiq/web'

   Padrino.mount('Sidekiq', app_class: 'Sidekiq::Web', app_root: Sidekiq::Web.root).to('/sidekiq')
   ```
5. Create any worker in `app/workers/`
6. Run `bundle exec sidekiq -r ./config/boot.rb`